# TFS 2010 ERROR on opening bug from power tools"Index (zero based)"

Tags: tfs

hi all i have a problem while opening the Work Item Types From `Power tools`

when I opens `BUG` then it gives an error "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero"

if i opens task , issue ,requirement etc then it will open successfully .
i have worked a lot on `BUG` workflow , if same problem exit then i will be fired from company.

because major work is happening on bug...
need urgent reply... i have Google it a lot but never find a good solution!

Comment: i have remove my cache but it still happens! same error

Comment: I haven't seen this error before, but what have you changed? Could you compared the original WITD with your customized? The error message sounds like the index field is not set, did you delete this field from Bug definition?

Comment: How many custom controls do you use? Did you use the work item designer to edit it or did you directly edit the xml? Make a backup of your current WI xml, remove all your custom controls, add them back individually and check which one is the faulty control/value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem . I have saved the BUG work flow incorrect. and allowed values have the group developers but after saving this work flow i have change the name of developers group to developer. so it cant read the group and the fields must be empty . that why i cant open workflow .
thanks for Ur reply!